# C# WinForm: Click Shows Help Tooltip & Shift+Click Shows Admin Panel Login?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am currently making my first tiny application to better automate what I do at work.

I have one panel that has a help (?) button at the top. When a user clicks it. It displays a little tooltip of what the program is used for and who to call for help. However, I also have a "Admin Panel" with a login box that I want to be displayed if you Shift+Click on the help button.

How can I go about this? I couldn't find anything for combo actions with a button.

i.e: Click shows tooltip help & Shift+Click brings up Admin area Login.

Forgive me if I am phrasing anything wrong or, any new mistakes.. I am learning as I go and brand new here.

Thank you for the answers in advance!

Comment: What does the current code for the click event look like? Please add it to the question.

Comment: The most important property of a UI is that it is *discoverable*.  Problem with this approach is that your user will never think that Shift+Click does anything special, you'll have to write a manual.  A "Login" menu option or toolbar button solves that problem.  And makes your code easy to write.

Comment: Please include at least partial code, even passed to your button_click should have shift status that you can check.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your button click event: -

```
if ((Control.ModifierKeys & Keys.Shift) != Keys.None)
{
    // show admin panel
}
else
{
    //show help tooltip
}
```